# How to retrieve the set of all classes that have necessary and sufficient restrictions

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api

In OWL API we can retrieve:

- the subclasses of a **specified** class
- the superclasses of a **specified** class
- the set of classes that are equivalent to a **specified** class

What i want is to retrieve from an ontology the set of *all* **Defined** classes (classes that has sufficient restriction, i.e., non primitive classes).

Kindly how can we do that?

for example:

```
OWLClass CheesyPizza = factory.getOWLClass(":CheesyPizza",pm); 
OWLClassExpression hasCheese_some_restriction = 
            factory.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(hasTopping, CheeseTopping);
OWLClassExpression Pizza_hasCheeseTopping_intersection =
            factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(Pizza, hasCheese_some_restriction);
OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom CheesyPizza_Definition = 
            factory.getOWLEquivalentClassesAxiom(CheesyPizza, Pizza_hasCheeseTopping_intersection);
tempChange.add(new AddAxiom(localOntology, CheesyPizza_Definition));
managerLocal.applyChanges(tempChange);
```

Cheesy Pizza is a **Defined** class, lets say we have in the Ontology many other Defined Classes (classes that has the necessary and sufficient).
I want to get Those classes (In other words i want to get the classes that have three lines in the yellow icon in protege).

I understand that there is no short hand function to do that. Therefore i added this section 2 of code:

```
OWLOntologyWalker walker = new OWLOntologyWalker(Collections.singleton(localOntology));
OWLOntologyWalkerVisitorEx<Object> visitor = new OWLOntologyWalkerVisitorEx<Object>(walker)
{
 @Override
 public Object visit(OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom ce)
  {
  System.out.println(" " + getCurrentAxiom());
// this will print the relating axioms EquivalentClasses(<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/CheesyPizza> ObjectIntersectionOf(<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/Pizza> ObjectSomeValuesFrom(<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/hasTopping> <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/CheeseTopping>)) )
// this axioms is correct and it is the axiom we want
// now lets try to get our Class CheesyPizza!
  for (OWLClass clazz : getCurrentAxiom().getClassesInSignature())  
  {
  if(! clazz.isAnonymous())
  System.out.println(clazz);
// this is printing 
//<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/CheesyPizza>
//<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/CheeseTopping>
//<http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/myontology/Pizza>
  }
}
```

I just want to get CheesyPizza, Cheesy Pizza is defined as shown in the 1st section of code, as an equivalent to an anonymous class of the intersection between the class pizza and hasCheese_some_restriction.

how to get the CheesyPizza class (its the only class that is not anonymous and has OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom attached to it. Why is this so complicated? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OWLOntology::getAxioms(OWLClass c)` - or `OWLOntology::axioms(OWLClass c)` on version 5 - should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you are passing a specific class c as a parameter, i don't want to get the axioms of a specific class, i want to get all the classes that are **D**efined from an Ontology, Kindly note that a **D**efined class according to owl is: A class that has at least one set of necessary and sufficient conditions is known as a **D**efined Class. i have modified the original question, and added an example, kindly help.

Comment: There is no shorthand for that, you'll have to go through all classes in the ontology signature (OWLOntology::getClassesInSignature() will provide that) and check if there are defining axioms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i wish it will be implemented in future versions. For now, i am trying to do it manually, I have added some code to this original post in section 2 code, kindly could you please tell me what am i missing? i am still not able to get CheesyPizza class, i am able to get all the classes that are involved in the axiom, but i need only to retrieve specifically the Defined class. Thanks for your time in advance. Sincere regards